# How do I set a new bit pattern in a certain position without changing the rest of the bits in C?

Tags: c, pointers, bit-manipulation, bit

Suppose I have the following `unsigned long val = 0xfedcba9876543210` and I want to change the 16 least significant bits to `0xabcd`. So, the original value will be changed to `unsigned long val = 0xfedcba987654abcd`. I already have a function `get` that can return `0x3210`, but I'm unsure how I can change this section of the value to `0xabcd`. For more context, here is what I am trying to implement:

```
void set_pattern(unsigned long* val, int i, unsigned short new_pattern) {
  // my attempt
  unsigned short old_pattern = get(val, i); // ex: returns 0x3210 when i = 0
  unsigned short* ptr = NULL;
  ptr = &old_pattern;
  *ptr = new_pattern;
}
```

When I tried my attempt, it seemed to not set the new pattern as I expected. Any help or feedback is appreciated in helping me gain a better understanding of C.

Comment: Don't be tempted to use pointer tricks; at best they're endian-dependent and at worst they cause UB by violating strict aliasing.  Just mask and or.  `*val = (*val & ~0xffffUL) | new_pattern;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain [Nate's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67156564/how-do-i-set-a-new-bit-pattern-in-a-certain-position-without-changing-the-rest-o#comment118705504_67156564), you want to apply a [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) to zero out the relevant bits, then apply the new bits with a bitwise or.

Let's do it with 32 bits and you want to change the the least 8.

Apply a bitmask to turn the least 8 bits to 0. `val = val & ~0xff`. `~0xff` is `0xffffff00`. Since [0 & x = 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), all the filled in bits will retain their value, and all the 0's will become 0 no matter their original value.

```
    0x12345678  val
AND 0xffffff00  ~0xff
  = 0x12345600
```

Now that the relevant bits have been masked out, turned to 0, we can overwrite just them with a bitwise or. `val = val | new_value`. [x | 0 = x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR). The irrelevant bits of new_value are 0. x | 0 = x. They will retain val's value. The relevant bits of val are 0. 0 | x = x. They will retain new_value's value.

```
   0x12345600  val
OR 0x000000ef  new_value
 = 0x123456ef
```

---

If you want to replace different bits, you need to shift the bitmask and replacement value the appropriate amount.

Let's say we want to replace 56 with ef instead. Each hex character is 4 bits, so we need to left shift both the bitmask and replacement value by 8 bits.

```
    0x12345678  val
AND 0xffff00ff  ~(0xff << 8) == ~0xff00
  = 0x12340078

    0x12340078  val
OR  0x0000ef00  new_value << 8 == 0xef00
 =  0x1234ef78
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, but what if I want to change set a new bit pattern for `0x7654` or `0xba98` from `0xfedcba9876543210` based on an index `i`? So, at `i = 0` I have `0x3210`, at `i = 1` I have `0x7654`, etc. I tried using bit shifting to do this, but it seems to change the bit pattern unexpectedly. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: @ArataKaizaki Assuming this relates to your question yesterday, with that number you won't get 0x7654 for `i = 1`. `i` in that case refers to the number of bits you shift. So if you'd want the bits marked X in 0xfedcba98XXXX3210, you would shift 16 bits. Two hexadecimal digits = 1 byte = 8 bits.

Comment: @ArataKaizaki You'd left shift the bitmask and your replacement value so they line up with which bits you want to replace. In the example above you if you wanted to change 56 to ef you'd need to left shift 8 bits (each hex character is 4 bits, you want to shift 2 characters). ~(0xff << 8) is your bitmask, ~0xff00, and 0xef << 8 becomes 0xef00.

Answer (score 0):

Well simple solution to it:

1. 0xfedcba9876543210 & 0xfedcba9876540000
2. 0xfedcba9876540000 | 0x000000000000abcd

Comment: NIce, and how do you get the right operand?

Comment: @DavidRanieri 0xfedcba9876540000 | 0x000000000000abcd OR using 0xfedcba9876540000 | 0xfedcba987654abcd produce the same result.
Considering the 2 least significant byte are to be changed, any of the methods can be used.